# Finite collection of linear functionals can be separated

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, consider a finite collection $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}\subset V^*$ of linear functionals on $V$. Then there exists a vector $v\in V$ such that $\alpha_i(v)\ne \alpha_j(v)$ whenever $i \neq j$.

Is this true? I believe this is true but not sure how to prove it. If not is there a counter example?

Comment: You mean 'whenver $i \neq j$'

Comment: Hint: show that $V=\cup V _{ij}$ iff $V=V_{ij}$ for some $i,j$ where $V_{ij}$ is subspace of $V.$ Then consider $V_{ij}=\ker(\alpha_i-\alpha_j).$

Comment: It is not true if the field $k$ is finite. If $k$ is infinite, you can follow Park's advice.